# Javascript - Searching through LI messes up display?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have an JavaScript to search through my `ul`. Here's my JavaScript

```
$('#SearchItemsFromList').keyup(function(){
   var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if(valThis == ""){
        $('#inventory > li > div').show();           
    } else {
        $('#inventory > li > div').each(function(){
            var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            (text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
        });
   };
});
```

Everything works great, but if I search then it messes up a display little bit. Is there a possibility to fix that somehow? I will add GIF, so you guys can get a better look at it. https://gyazo.com/994f26d66a467fd525e3867792400710

Here's my HTML for `ul` (I added HTML to JSFiddle, because it was too big.)
https://jsfiddle.net/8egqgx91/

Comment: Could you show some CSS code?

Comment: Hmm, Alright. I am using that: http://materializecss.com/ & That https://github.com/zavoloklom/material-design-hierarchical-display

Comment: Could you pls provide a valid jsfiddle example with js and css code and it shows where the problem is.

Comment: I already did with GIF, I can't put that code into JSFiddle

Comment: I suppose that we can only solve the problem effectively after you show your code or simplified version of your code. Or what we can do is only guess...

Comment: Which parts are needed to see in the JSFiddle then though?